# vb6 sql database error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, vb6, odbc

I am attempting to fill textboxes with info pulled by the SQL query found in this code:

```
Dim Sqlstring As String
Dim rstCurrentTicket As Recordset

Sqlstring = "SELECT SubmiterName, Department, Description, Urgency, SubmitDate,     ResolvedDate 
               FROM TroubleTickets 
              WHERE Title = " + Trim(TicketComboBox.Text)

SET rstCurrentTicket = cnnSel.OpenRecordset(Sqlstring)

Do While Not rstCurrentTicket.EOF

  TicketComboBox.AddItem (rstCurrentTicket!TroubleTicketTitle)

Loop
```

the debugger is currently flaging the Set rstCurrentTicket statement. and giving me an an error that says

> RUN TIME ERROR 3146 ODBC Call failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Title is a string, try changing your assignment to `Sqlstring` to this:

```
Sqlstring = "Select SubmiterName, Department, Description, Urgency, SubmitDate,     ResolvedDate from TroubleTickets where Title ='" & Trim(TicketComboBox.Text) & "'"
```

You'll need the single quote qualifiers around your TicketComboBox text to tell the SQL statement you're working with a String.

Comment: I did as you suggested and am now getting a different error. it now says Compile Error: Method or Data member not found. and the debugger highlights the method I am using to implement this code: ' Public Sub SelectButton_Click()'

Comment: @John Hard to say what's going on without looking at more of your project, but is there a SelectButton_Click() event missing in your project?  If there is such an event perhaps it's out of scope for the code attempting to call it.

Comment: its defenitely in the project ive tried public and private.. thanks tho